# What are the common platform names in Buck?

Tags: c++, buck

I would like to build a cross-platform `cxx_library` with [buck](/questions/tagged/buck). I have different `cpp` files for the different platforms. According to [the docs](https://buckbuild.com/rule/cxx_library.html), I can handle this using `platform_srcs`, which is:

> ...a list of pairs where the first element is an un-anchored regex (in java.util.regex.Pattern syntax) against which the platform name is matched".

- What do these platform names look like?
- What are some example regexes I could use for OSX, Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following:

- Android: `android.*`
- iPhone: `iphoneos.*`
- iPhone Simulator: `iphonesimulator*`
- Linux: `linux.*`
- macOS: `macos.*`
- Windows: `windows.*`

Don't forget to turn on `should_remap_host_platform` in order to avoid `'default'` platform weirdness. In your `.buckconfig`:

```
[cxx]
  should_remap_host_platform = true
```

See: https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/2073

Answer (score 1):

Android: `android`

iPhone: `iphoneos`

iPhone Simulator: `iphonesimulator`

Linux: Unsure

OSX: Unsure

Windows: `^windows.*`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I won't close this out until linux and macos are figured out because they are critical for me. What I can say is that (my) macos does not match osx, mac or macos, which was unexpected!

Comment: I think there may be a bug in Buck. I can only match on `default` on macos.

Comment: `default` is just the host platform.  It might be worthwhile to open up an issue to get better docs explaining this.